# which PDO::PARAM_* to use with a SET() datatype?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, set, sqldatatypes

I have an array of values, and one of the values is another array (see below). I implode the inner-array so that it becomes v<sub>0</sub>,v<sub>1</sub>,v<sub>x</sub> and I'm inserting it into a column of a mysql database where the datatype is `SET()`

```
a = array(
    "first"=>"foo",
    "second"=>array("b","a","r"), // this becomes "second"=>"b,a,r",
    "third"=>"bang"
)
```

My question is which `PDO::PARAM_*` should I use?
*(Initially I would think `PARAM_STR`, but I'm not sure if PDO will do something that won't work with `SET()`).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PARAM_STR` should do the job correctly. It will escape values and add single quotes around comma separated list.